# There is an app that can do screenshots in MacOSX Lion, what's the name?

Tags: screen-capture

There is an app that can do screenshots in MacOSX Lion, what's the name?

It comes from the OS, not a 3rd party app.

Comment: http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=61544

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The built-in application is called Grab. You can find it under the Utilities folder in Applications.

You can also use keyboard shortcuts to take screen shots. Here's a quick guide from [Apple](http://www.apple.com/findouthow/mac/#capturescreen):

> In Mac OS X, you can use simple keyboard shortcuts to do all sorts of things, including capturing images of what’s on your Mac screen. For example, you can take a screen shot of your entire screen by holding down the Command and Shift keys and pressing a 3.
>
> If you hold down the Command and Shift keys and press 4, Mac OS X turns the cursor into crosshairs you can use to select whatever portion of your display you’d like to capture in a screen shot.
>
> If you immediately hit the Spacebar after typing Command-Shift-4, Mac OS X replaces those crosshairs with a little camera. Using the camera, you can take a screen shot of the Dock, the entire menu bar, a single open menu, the desktop, or any open window.

Comment: I've always used the keyboard shortcuts.  I didn't know the application had a name.

Comment: IIRC Grab was the name of the app even back in NeXTSTEP days.

Comment: "simple keyboard shortcuts" is worded a bit ironic by Apple. I wonder how many non-power users can remember that combo... I know how to do it from muscle memory (because I use it a lot), but I wouldn't be able to write the combination down.

Answer (score 6):

You can also take screenshots with Preview via File -> Take Screen Shot. This gives you the following options:

- From Selection...
- From Window...
- From Entire Screen

Each screenshot is captured in a separate Preview window so it is mostly useful to collect screenshots and process them afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I generally use the built-in screen grab utility. If you hold down the **Control** key in addition to the other keys (i.e. **Command-Shift-4**), the captured image will be sent to the clipboard rather than being saved as a file. I find this useful when I'm pasting the screen grab directly into a document.

Apple's documentation of this feature is available from the Help Menu. Search for **Shortcuts for taking pictures of the screen**

There are a number of third-party applications that offer various enhancements to the screen grabbing experience. For example if you plan to do a lot of post-production manipulation, [Layers](http://layersapp.com/) will save every element on the screen as a separate layer of a .psd document.